# How to visualize the data if one participant has multiple entries in different rows?

Tags: r

I am currently working on a dataset which consists of multiple participants. Some participants have participated all followups, whereas others have skipped some followups.

For example, in the dataset below, participant 2 only participated the 3rd followup, and participant 3 only participated the 2nd and the 3rd followup. You can also see that some participants have more than 1 rows of entry because they have several followups.

[image: Example]

The original dataset only has the 1st and the 2nd column. Since I am aiming to create a progress chart like this

[image: Chart]

I have tried to create extra columns for each visit by using the code below:

```
participant <- c(1,1,1,2,3,3,4,5,5,5 )
visit <- c(1,2,3,3,2,3,1,1,2,3)

df <- data.frame(participant, visit)
df[,3] <- as.integer(df$visit=="1")
df[,4] <- as.integer(df$visit=="2")
df[,5] <- as.integer(df$visit=="3")

colnames(df)[colnames(df) %in% c("V3","V4","V5")] <- c(
  "Visit1","Visit2","Visit3")
```

However, I still experience a hard time combining rows of the same participant, and hence I could not proceed to making the chart (which I also have no clue about). I have tried the 'reshape' function but it did not work out. group_by function also did not work out and still showed the original dataset

```
df1 <- df[,-2]

df1 %>%
  group_by(participant)
```

What function should I use this case for:

1. combining rows of the same participant?
2. how to produce the progress chart?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Please don't post data as images. Take a look at how to make a [great reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for ways of showing data. The gold standard for providing data is using `dput(head(NameOfYourData))`, *editing* your question and putting the `structure()` output into the question.

Comment: `group_by` just groupes the data in an abstract way. You have to apply a function (usally used in `mutate()` or `summarise()`) to change the data.frame.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your `df` you could produce the chart with

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = as.factor(visit), 
             y = as.factor(participant), 
             fill = as.factor(visit))) +
  geom_tile(aes(width = 0.7, height = 0.7), color = "black") + 
  scale_fill_grey() +
  xlab("Visit") + 
  ylab("Participants") +
  guides(fill = "none")
```

[image]

If you need your data.frame in a wide format (similar to the image shown but with only one row per participant), use

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(value = 1) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = visit,
    values_from = value,
    names_glue = "Visit{visit}",
    values_fill = 0)
```

to get

```r
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  participant Visit1 Visit2 Visit3
        <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1           1      1      1      1
2           2      0      0      1
3           3      0      1      1
4           4      1      0      0
5           5      1      1      1
```

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much for this! I think I have overcomplicated the problem by creating extra columns indicating separate visit. Thank you so much!

I will go ahead and read more about the ggplot2 package.

Comment: @HelenAndrews Take a look at http://r-statistics.co/Top50-Ggplot2-Visualizations-MasterList-R-Code.html for nice examples of `ggplot2`-plots. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a way to `dummify` a variable.
There are several ways to do that.

I like the `fastDummies` package. You can use `dummy_cols`, with `remove_selected_columns=TRUE`.

```
df %>% fastDummies::dummy_cols(select_columns = 'visit',
                                remove_selected_columns = TRUE)

   participant visit_1 visit_2 visit_3
1            1       1       0       0
2            1       0       1       0
3            1       0       0       1
4            2       0       0       1
5            3       0       1       0
6            3       0       0       1
7            4       1       0       0
8            5       1       0       0
9            5       0       1       0
10           5       0       0       1
```

You may want to pipe in some `summarise`operation to make the table even cleaner, as in:

```
df %>% fastDummies::dummy_cols(select_columns = 'visit', remove_selected_columns = TRUE)%>%
        group_by(participant)%>%
        summarise(across(starts_with('visit'), max))

# A tibble: 5 x 4
  participant visit_1 visit_2 visit_3
        <dbl>   <int>   <int>   <int>
1           1       1       1       1
2           2       0       0       1
3           3       0       1       1
4           4       1       0       0
5           5       1       1       1
```

In a certain way, this looks a bit like a pivoting operation too.
You may be interested in using `dplyr::pivot_wider` here too

- EDIT: @MartinGal had just given a similar answer, I removed a very similar version of his pivot_wider

Comment: Thank you so much GuedesBF, I have indeed tried with the function and it worked! Now I can work with my actual dataset which consists with thousands of data point, this really helps! Thank you and please have a nice weekend.

Comment: I am glad i could help. Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers